# How do I keep a label centered in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, centering

In `WinForms` I am using a `Label` to display different messages like success, failure, etc.

I'd like to center that label in the center form. I want a solution that will keep it centered whether there's just one word or a whole sentence in the label.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Set `Label`'s `AutoSize` property to `False`, `TextAlign` property to `MiddleCenter` and `Dock` property to `Fill`.

Comment: thanks decyclone, it worked. can u plz guide what Dock does  ?

Comment: With `Control.Dock` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx), you can dock (stick) a control to a certain side of the container. For example `Left`, `Top`, `Right` or `Bottom`. `Fill` tells the control to take all the available space in the container.

Comment: Unless you want the label to fill the entire space available to it, you may wish to set the Dock property to "None" as suggested by user3866622 in his/her programmatic solution.

Comment: Worked, but I didn't need to do anything to the `Dock` setting.

Comment: `Dock` setting was unnecessary. Changing the `AutoSize` property gives the label a bounding box that you can manually adjust the size of.

Comment: Anchors can be used instead of dock as well.

Answer (score 17):

You will achive it with setting property Anchor: None.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again every time I come across it.

Answer (score 17):

Some minor additional content for setting programmatically:

```
Label textLabel = new Label() { 
        AutoSize = false, 
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, 
        Dock = DockStyle.None, 
        Left = 10, 
        Width = myDialog.Width - 10
};
```

Dockstyle and Content alignment may differ from your needs. For example, for a simple label on a wpf form I use DockStyle.None.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to dock label in whole available area, just set SizeChanged event instead of TextChanged. Changing each letter will change the width property of label as well as its text when autosize property set to True. So, by the way you can use any formula to keep label centered in form.

```
private void lblReport_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblReport.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - lblReport.Size.Width) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer didn't work for me for two reasons:

1. I had `BackColor` set so setting `AutoSize = false` and `Dock = Fill` causes the background color to fill the whole form
2. I couldn't have `AutoSize` set to false anyway because my label text was dynamic

Instead, I simply used the form's width and the width of the label to calculate the left offset:

```
MyLabel.Left = (this.Width - MyLabel.Width) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar, but on a form with a background image, I found that when the text in the label changed the repaints were obvious with this method, so I did the following:
* Set the label AutoSize to true and TextAlign to MiddleCenter

Then, each time the text changed (mine was done using a timer) I called the following method:

```
    private Point GetPosition()
    {
        int y = (this.Height / 2) - (label1.Height / 2);
        int x = (this.Width / 2) - (label1.Width / 2);
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

And set the label's Location property to this return value. This ensured that the label was always in the center of the form when the text changed and the repaints for a full-screen form weren't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out the following code snippet:

```
private Point CenterOfMenuPanel<T>(T control, int height=0) where T:Control {
    Point center = new Point( 
        MenuPanel.Size.Width / 2 - control.Width * 2,
        height != 0 ? height : MenuPanel.Size.Height / 2 - control.Height / 2);

    return center;
}
```

It's Really Center

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'this.' being the form you are on with lblName as the item you wish to centre. Additionally 'offsetInt' will allow you to position the label left or right of the centre. lblName.Location.Y maintains the existing Y height on the form.

```
lblName.Location = new Point((int)((this.Width - lblName.Width) / 2) +/- offsetInt, lblName.Location.Y);
```